# Are virtual tables part of the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

I am reading about the implementation of late binding polymorphism in C++ and I learned about virtual tables and virtual pointers.

Then I searched on the C++ standard ([ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf)) to get more information about how this behavior should be implemented.

Unfortunately I found nothing relevant in this massive standard except the definition of *Virtual functions* at §10.3 so I suppose the concept of `__vptr` is used by GCC but could be implemented differently.

Is there a standard or a paper that describe how virtual methods should be implemented?

Comment: How they are implemented is an implementation detail.  It's not part of the C++ standard, since different platforms and architectures can vary too much for any one implementation to be optimal for all platforms.

Comment: Does it means you could have late-binding mechanism that is not implemented using neither virtual tables nor virtual pointers?

Comment: I remember hearing someone at Microsoft say they'd experimented with virtual stub dispatching as a potential replacement to vtables. That eliminated the extra indirection in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not defined by the standard. They are instead *implementation* concepts, rather like a *stack* or a *heap*.

The standard is helpful in permitting the implementation of polymorphism to be carried out in a certain way, for example, the address of the first member variable of a `class` doesn't need to be the address of an instance of that class if that class is a polymorphic type.